# Gravity Disabled on Robot Pinned to World

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a simple robot with four links and four revolute joints.  The first joint is pinned to the world.  When I run the simulation, the robot is not affected by gravity.  I know gravity is enabled because when I drag another object like a box and drop it into the world, it falls down.  I suspect that gravity is not affecting my four-link robot because it is pinned to the world.  Could this be the case?  How can I enable gravity for my robot?

**Update:**  The problem was fixed by specifying collision elements for each link in the robot. This is strange since collisions and dynamics should be decoupled.  Should this be considered a bug?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/178/gravity-disabled-on-robot-pinned-to-world/) by [liangfok](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51/liangfok/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-11-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2012-11-12**:
can you post your robot model?  (with and without collision bodies?)

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2012-11-30**:
can you change your question's title to reflect the issue?  i.e. dynamics disabled if missing collision element?  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It appears if a model does not have any collision elements, it behaves statically, [ticketed here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/274/dynamics-disabled-if-link-does-not-contain).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2012-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-01-11**:
[This issue has been resolved](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/274).

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-01-11**:
[This issue has been resolved](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/274).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Creating a joint between a model and the world (aka pinning the model to the world), will enforce a joint constraint between the robot and world. This is usually only used if you want to the robot to remain in on fixed location.

I think you may have pinned the robot, and it looks like gravity is not working because the joint is just holding the robot in place.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-11-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1